# broken package system after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I performed 2 system in-box upgrades (18.04->18.10, then 18.10->19.04) yesterday.

Today, I've got a broken package system:

```
    sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkf5configgui5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed
 libkf5guiaddons5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installed
 libkf5kdcraw5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.6.1~) but it is not installed or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.6.1~) but it is not installed
 libkf5kexiv2-15.0.0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installed or
                                libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installed
 libkf5syntaxhighlighting5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed or
                                      libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed
 libkf5waylandclient5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed
 libpoppler-qt5-1 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installed
 libqt5help5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed or
                        libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
 libqt5opengl5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but it is not installed or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.9.0~beta) but it is not installed
 libqt5printsupport5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installed or
                                libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installed
                Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installed or
                         libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installed
 libqt5quickcontrols2-5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                   libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5quicktemplates2-5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                    libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5quickwidgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0) but it is not installed or
                                libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.8.0) but it is not installed
 libqt5svg5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5waylandclient5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5waylandcompositor5 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
                            Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                     libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5webenginecore5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5webenginewidgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                    libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but it is not installed or
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.9.0~beta) but it is not installed
 libqt5widgets5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installed
 libqt5x11extras5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 libqtwebkit4 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installed or
                         libgl1 but it is not installed
                Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
 librenaissance0 : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 librenaissance0-dev : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 libva-glx2 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 libwxgtk3.0-0v5 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 lusernet.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 lynkeos.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 lyx : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0) but it is not installed
 mesa-utils : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 mpdcon.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 openimageio-tools : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
                     Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not installed
 paje.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 phantomjs : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed or
                      libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
 pikopixel.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 plopfolio.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 poe.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 price.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 projectcenter.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: gorm.app but it is not installed
 python-pyqt5-dbg : Depends: python-pyqt5 (= 5.12.1+dfsg-1) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libqt5designer5 (>= 5.9.1) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2) but it is not installed
 qbittorrent : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects : Depends: qml-module-qtquick2 but it is not installed
                                 Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtquick-controls : Depends: qml-module-qtquick2 but it is not installed
                               Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                        libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtquick-controls2 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                         libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.5.0) but it is not installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.5.0) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 qml-module-qtquick-templates2 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 qt5-gtk-platformtheme : Depends: libqt5gui5 (= 5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1) but it is not installed or
                                  libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg) but it is not installed
 qt5-qmltooling-plugins : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.10.0) but it is not installed or
                                   libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.10.0) but it is not installed
 qtwayland5 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed or
                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2+dfsg~) but it is not installed
 systempreferences.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 talksoup.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 terminal.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 textedit.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 timemon.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 virtualbox-5.2 : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not installed
 vlc-plugin-qt : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.8.0) but it is not installed
 vlc-plugin-video-output : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 volumecontrol.app : Depends: gnustep-back0.27 (>= 0.27.0) but it is not installed
 vprerex : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
 x11-utils : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: libgl1 but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.10.2-4) but it is not installed
 zenity : Depends: libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 (>= 2.15.1) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I've tried `sudo apt -f install`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and, as above `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, all resulting in the same output.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Comment: how do your sources look? add a screenshot to your question. you'll probably have to uninstall evey package mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt download libglapi-mesa
sudo dpkg -i libglapi-mesa-*.deb
```

Make sure that the Ubuntu version of deb file (`libglapi-mesa_19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1_amd64.deb`) is the same as running on your machine. If not then you may have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` keeping only `disco` related ppa and remove ppa of previous distros and run the above commands.

I had a similar issue with dependencies of `libqt5gui5` and `libgl1`. When you will try to install `libgl1` using `sudo apt install libgl1` you will find it's dependencies at the top of the output. Try going to root recursively by trying to install dependencies. You will find `libglapi-mesa` installed but from the previous version of Ubuntu(at least in my case, in your case you may find some other package conflicting).

Answer (score 0):

With apologies for the late reply, I realized I'd had the forethought of keeping /home on a separate partition, so I simply wiped the OS install, installed 19.04 fresh and re-pointed /home.  As my files in .config were maintained in my home folder, reinstalling some additional packages left me with a fully working system in far less time than trying to debug the pieces I got to keep when I broke my Linux :)

Thanks to all who read and especially those who replied.

Best,
-Ray